# How to get fast from Meta to Main?

Tags: soporte

If you are in Main page, you can click Help, then Meta. But if you are in Meta on Questions page, how to get fast back to Main page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click over the StackExhange main menu, and there you have the option to the main site and the meta, and below you can find the other sites where you have an account sorted by your reputation

[image]